# Testcases of XPath 2.0 expressions which can test if a parser is support XPath 2.0

Tags: xpath, testcase, xpath-2.0

I am try to test if a parser support XPath 2.o. Can someone give me some basic XPath 2.o expression which will pass if the parser support XPath 2.o and will fail if the parser only support 1.0.

Do not have to be fancy strings, just 4-5 basic XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT provides `system-property('xsl:version')` for identifying version information.  Unfortunately, XPath has no such function to distinguish between XPath 1.0 vs XPath 2.0.  You can probe the library by calling a function that's only defined in XPath 2.0 and see if it fails.  Here are a few such functions:

- current-dateTime()
- lower-case(), upper-case(), ends-with()
- matches(), replace(), tokenize()

Wikipedia has a more extensive list of library [XPath functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0#Function_library), grouped by category, and marked per XPath 1.0 vs XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can think of are

```
()
1 eq 1
abs(3)
''''
*:x
```